# Do Irish bands/music fans have a special thing for Kraftwerk?

Tags: cover

Kraftwerk have never seemed to me to be the most obvious band to *cover*, and yet

- U2 have covered [Neon Lights](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FWwfsvR27HI)
- The Divine Comedy have done a version of [Radioactivity](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lCxsEJ9xYfE)
- The Frank and Walters often give [The Model](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=S8RsW1PS3Ug) their own special treatment live

Is this just because Kraftwerk are quite famous and there are quite a few Irish bands? Or is there proportionately a lot of interest in Kraftwerk in Ireland?

Comment: Seriously? Three covers is so unusual? There are [about fifty covers of The Model](http://www.whosampled.com/Kraftwerk/The-Model-(Das-Model)/covered/), so nothing unusual about that. [Bono has talked about U2's Kraftwerk cover](http://www.rollingstone.com/music/news/9-biggest-revelations-in-bonos-bbc-interview-about-u2-20140203), plus them covering Kraftwerk isn't exactly unusual considering *Achtung Baby* etc.

Comment: @BCdotWEB sounds like you're halfway to an answer there.